# Combine Multiple NSMutableDictionary

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a recursive function that's adding the previous dictionary to the new dictionary but using **addEntriesFromDictionary** gives me error

Here's my sample code (EDITED)

```
    func fetchAllSWApiList(strUrl: String, strArrayCallback: NSMutableDictionary){
    let swApiHandler = SwApiHandler()
    let url = strUrl

    swApiHandler.requestSWPApi(url, completionHandler: {(response, error) in
        if let responseDictionary = response as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            print("Did Detect a dictionary")
            strArrayCallback.addEntriesFromDictionary(responseDictionary)
        }
        guard  let nextPage: String = response!["next"]! as? String else {
            print("End Of Page")
            print(strArrayCallback.description)
           return
        }

        print(nextPage)
        self.fetchAllSWApiList(nextPage, strArrayCallback: strArrayCallback)

    })

}
```

If you have a better solution in my code that will return the combined list from the fetched data recursively the better.

EDIT: here's the error

> NSDictionary is not implicitly convertible to '[NSObject: AnyObject]';
>   did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

after that my code will become should I leave it as it is or edit the NSpbject part?

```
strArrayCallback.addEntriesFromDictionary(response! as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

**EDIT2:**
incase you're wondering what's the JSON model looks like here's a pic of it

[image]

Comment: "gives me error" please do not make us guess. What was the error?

Comment: @Jonah please see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

You should cast your response to the Dictionary type that you're expecting, by doing something like:

```
if let responseDictionary = response as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    strArrayCallback.addEntriesFromDictionary(responseDictionary)
}
```

Comment: somehow it gets inside the  if statement but it's not appending in my existing dictionary. Please see my edited question